POSIX-Extended RE for substrings that start with a prefix, end with a suffix and whose inner part does not contain any element of a given set
I have an input string S and three parameters: a prefix string (denoted by A), a suffix string (denoted by B) and a set N of strings.
Given these three parameters, is it possible to generate a single POSIX-Extended regular expression R to match all shortest substrings of S that start with A, continue as a string (possibly the empty string) that does not contain any element of N, and end with B (assuming that the substrings are extracted from left to right, i.e. from the first character of the input to the last one)? If yes, how?
To give an example,
A = "ab", B = "bc", N = ["a", "cb"];
R = ?
S = "0abaabacbbcd1e2ababcdbcbcdbc4abbcabcbc5abcbdbcabcdbca";
matches = ["abcdbc", "abbc", "abcbc", "abcdbc"]


A, B and elements of {N} do not overlap? otherwise abc is shorter than abcdbc and all your matches contain a

@jhnc: yes, prefix and suffix do not overlap with each other and with elements of N.

One of the challenges here (that will make the regex long) is that it should not be checked that the prefix includes a possible start of a negative, while it should be checked that the prefix part has a possible start of another occurrence of the prefix.

@trincot I don't understand your final clause. it is stated they don't overlap, so is it not just the concatenation of match(A) not-match(A,B,N) match(B) that is needed?

Imagine prefix: abab, and negative: abc, then ababab should not be the (start of the) match, since then you could have started 2 positions later, and we are told we need the shortest match. On the other hand, it is quite ok to continue after the prefix with c, to get ababc, as the check for negatives should only start after the prefix. This means that the number of distinct states increases when the prefix can overlap with itself.

I had tried this here: ab(b+|([^abc]|b[^ac]|c[^ab])*c?)bc (regex101)

@bobblebubble does not work, as it matches: abccbfccbc. the c[^ab] can match cc and then this can be succeeded by b

@DuesserBaest good catch, thank you! Almost sure there are more flaws...  I'm curious if someone provides a working solution, won't play with it further, I guess.

A general solution (with input being the prefix, the list of negatives, and the suffix) to produce a regex is going to be far from simple. In the OP I don't see any attempt at it, let be a problem statement that relates to their work.

@DuesserBaest Do you think this would fix it? Just tried quickly, probably not or some fresh issue. :D

@bobblebubble, "abccdbc" should have a match.

@trincot thank you! Yes, that doesn't work out as meant to... I'm out from this. :D

The question (at least parts of it) could fit better here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions or here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata

A regular expression that matches anything that contains any element of N is easy. The hard part is to generate its complement. There are several steps:

Generate a DFA for matching anything that contains any element of N. (You may find it more convenient to generate a NFA first, e.g. from a regex, and then convert it to a DFA. This is covered in any relevant textbook).
Turn any non-accepting states into accepting states and vice versa.
Generate a RE from the DFA following e,g, this algorithm.

Note, you want to add your suffix to the exclusion list to yield shortest matches, otherwise the result will match e.g. abcdbcbc.
Edit there is a situation where this will not work, namely, when there is a suffix of the prefix such that the prefix followed by that suffix contains nore than one copy of the prefix. For example, if the prefix is bb, then bbb contains bb twice, and it would match, giving a non-shortest match. This is easy to fix. Identify all such suffixes and at step 1, generate a DFA for matching anything that contains any element of N or starts with one of these suffixes. This is easy to do from a corresponding regexp. Then build its complement as above.

Building the NFA/DFA is the challenging bit, because a negative is allowed to occur in -- or partly overlap with -- the prefix and the suffix. Yet the prefix is not allowed to partly overlap with itself to produce a second occurrence, as then the match should have started later.

@trincotI don't see any problem. First you check the prefix. This is trivial, it occurs exactly once, no need to check for overlap with anything. Then you check the complement of "anything including any of these strings". This is the hard part but also straightforward. Then you check the suffix. This is also trivial. The trick is to include the suffix in "anything including any of these strings".

I see complexity in when the prefix occurs a second time, overlapping with its own. Then while you have already processed the prefix, you must prevent that partial remainder to occur immediately after. But that should only happen in that state, as later on you only want to prevent a full occurring prefix to occur before starting on the suffix. This all is slightly different than the part where you want to prevent the negatives to occur, as that only kicks in after the prefix, no matter if the prefix happens to already have ended in a few beginning characters of a negative...

You write "no need to check for overlap with anything", but be aware that only the shortest matches should be produced, so by consequence the prefix should not occur a second time (before the start of the suffix), because if there is such an occurrence, the current substring is not the shortest. This makes the prefix much like a negative, but the difference is that a negative cannot occur after the prefix, while the prefix is not allowed to occur already earlier (overlapping with itself). This increases the number of states of the DFA, and doesn't make it that trivial.

@Tricot oh I see what you mean. If you don't want e.g. "ababbc" to match, just add the prefix to the negative list as well.

But that is the point: the prefix and the negatives in the negative list do not follow the exact same rules. The negatives should only be rejected after the prefix has been consumed, while the prefix should not re-occur after the very first character of the potential match. Those are two different starting points and complicate the DFA.

@trincot yes you are right, one should avoid certain suffixes of the prefix. Not a problem either, one can easily identify these suffixes. "Everything that is not such suffix" is still a regular language so one can combine it with other parts of this. It may be a lot of work but it's all mechanical work. I will fix the answer when I have time

What you have suggested as an edit will not cover it, because that potential suffix of the prefix should be rejected only right after the prefix was consumed, but not anywhere else where the other negatives should not occur. You need more states.

@trincot Read carefully, "contains any element of N or starts with one of these suffixes".

@trincot At what point do you see that any of these suffixes will be rejected not immediately after the prefix was consumed? The middle part comes immediately after the prefix and the suffixes are considered only at the beginning of that middle part.

"and the suffixes are considered only at the beginning of that middle part": yes, I see I still have missed this nuance in your answer. After rereading the phrase again for the 10th time (lol), I see it does cover for what I was concerned about. But then I would not call that "easy". It is true we can consider it mechanical, but I find it quite a challenge to write a program that produces such a DFA.

The following regex will ensure that you get a match having prefix and suffix and the capture group will ensure the content inside.
ab(?=(?:(?!ab).)*bc)(.*?)bc

Demo
This regex ensures that there wont be any underlying string ab after the prefix ab.
In the following code,
The first capture group m[1] will only capture the inside string. and m[0] represent the full matched String. You can then easily go iterate substring over the m[1] to pick your final result.


 const R = /ab(?=(?:(?!ab).)*bc)(.*?)bc/gm;
 
 const N = ["a","cb"];

const str = `0abaabacbbcd1e2ababcdbcbcdbc4abbcabcbc5abcbdbcabcdbca`;
let m;

while ((m = R.exec(str)) !== null) {    
    let found=false;
    for(const val of N)
    { 
      if(m[1].includes(val))
      {
        found=true;
        break;
      }
   }
   if(!found)
    console.log(m[0]);
}




POSIX-Extended RE does not support look-arounds. Also, your regex finds a match in "abcadbc", but it shouldn't.

'abcadbc' it is supposed to get matched but as I said because it wont come out as a result since  I check substring in my solution

The for loop and includes is not something that fits with the question. The asker is asking for a regex that gives the matches, without further loops, string searches, ...etc.

Really? I thought the tags in the OP refers to pseudocode and algorithm alongside  regex. Anyway I might delete the ans since POSIX EXTENDED RE doesn’t  support lookahead. I also think it is totally not possible to implement  a regex that will fit everything  he demands. If it was then OP would not have come up with an array of exclusion.

I think you misunderstood. The algorithm is for generating (as output) the regex, based on the input (prefix, list of exclusions, suffix). But when running the regex there shouldn't be any other code necessary but for executing the regex to retrieve the matches.

If lookarounds were allowed and lazy matching, maybe ab(?:[^ac]|c(?!b(?!c)))*?bc (not even sure if this one works as meant to)

if lookaround was possible then may be this abcbc would have created problem.

@MustofaRizwan Indeed! That's why I used (?!c) inside (?!b) after c.

But the problem is , the ignore list can be long enough with various combination. And may not be feasible to sort out by the way that you have provided.

Absolutely, it's not really useable for being generated, at least not in a simple way. And also it's not what was asked for... but (if it works) it can be used for testing inputs.

Things could have been done with my solution even if I dont use lookahead. But I have been made understood that here pseudocode and algorithm means only a regex solution, so I didn't go further with it :)
